# Warning: Passing argument makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, function, structure

I've written some code for a bookstore program that contains a function that scans for details on each book entered. However, I am getting a warning (34:4) from the argument that is meant to pass the title of the book. I'm assuming it has something to do with the title being the only variable containing characters, but I'm not sure why this is an issue. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BOOKS 10 //Maximum number of books that exist in an inventory
#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 20//Maximum number of characters in a book title

struct Book { //Declare struct Book
    int _isbn; //International Standard Book Number
    float _price; //Book price
    int _year; //Publication year
    char _title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE]; //Book title
    int _qty; //Book Quantity
};

int menu();
void displayInventory(const struct Book book[], const int size);
void searchInventory(const struct Book book[], const int isbn, const int size);
void addBook(struct Book book[], int *size);
void checkPrice(const struct Book book[], const int size);
/* main program */
int main(void) {

    struct Book book[MAX_BOOKS]; //An array of Book representing the inventory
    int size = 0; //Number of books in the inventory. The inventory is initially empty

    //Display a welcome message:
    printf("Welcome to the book store\n");
    printf("=========================\n");

    int select = menu();
    switch (select)
    {
        case 0: //Exit the program
            displayInventory(book, &size);
            break;

        case 1: //Display the inventory
            break;

        case 2: //Add a book to the inventory
            addBook(book, &size);
            break;

        case 3: //Check price
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

int menu()
{

        int option = 0;

        printf("Please select from the following options:\n");
        printf("1) Display the inventory\n");
        printf("2) Add a book to the inventory\n");
        printf("3) Check price.\n");
        printf("0) Exit\n");
        printf("Select ");

        scanf("%d", &option);


    return option;
}

void displayInventory(const struct Book book[], const int size)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (size > 0) {
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("ISBN      Title               Year Price   Quantity\n");
    printf("---------+-------------------+----+-------+--------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
    printf("%-10d%-20s%-5d$%-8.2f%-8d", book[i]._isbn, book[i]._title,    book[i]._year, book[i]._price, book[i]._qty);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("The inventory is empty!");
    }
}


void searchInventory(const struct Book book[], const int isbn, const int size)
{
    printf("Not implemented");

    return;
}

void addBook(struct Book book[], int *size)
{
    if(*size== MAX_BOOKS) {
        printf("the inventory is full.");
    }

    else {       
        printf("ISBN\n");
        scanf("%d", &book[*size]._isbn);
        printf("Title\n");
        scanf("%c", &book[*size]._title);
        printf("Price\n");
        scanf("%lf", &book[*size]._price);
        printf("Year\n");
        scanf("%d", &book[*size]._year);
        printf("Qty\n");
        scanf("%d", &book[*size]._qty); 
        printf("Book successfully added to inventory\n");

        *size++;
        }


}

void checkPrice(const struct Book book[], const int size)
{
    printf("Not implemented");

    return;
}
```

Comment: `displayInventory(book, &size);` type of 2nd argument of `displayInventory` is `int`, not `int*`. Remove `&`.  --> `displayInventory(book, size);`

Comment: Thank you, I've only just started using functions with structures and arrays so I'm making quite a few mistakes that are requiring a great deal of trial and error.